# Del tag not closing on WooCommerce sale price (IE only)

Tags: php, mysql, css, woocommerce

On Woocommerce 2, products on sale display the regular price in a `<del>` tag, followed by the sale price (which is itself in an `<ins>` tag). IE8 is showing a `<del>` tag on the regular price—and then reapplies the `<del>` on all text after the sale item (even down to the footer). Only the regular item should display a `<del>` tag. All other browsers are displaying this correctly. It seems to be on class-wc-product-variation.php. I see this reference to the  tag insertion:

`public function get_price_html() {`

```
    if ( $this->price !== '' ) {
        if ( $this->price == $this->sale_price && $this->sale_price < $this->regular_price ) {

            $price = '<del>' . woocommerce_price( $this->regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . woocommerce_price( $this->sale_price ) . '</ins>';
            $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', $price, $this );

        } elseif ( $this->price > 0 ) {

            $price = woocommerce_price( $this->price );
            $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html', $price, $this );

        } else {

            $price = __( 'Free!', 'woocommerce' );
            $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', $price, $this );

        }
    } else {
        $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_empty_price_html', '', $this );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

I don't see anything in there that should make IE fail to close the `<del>` tag. I didn't see anything in WooCommerce's CSS files at all relating to `<del>`, `<strike>` or `line-through`.

Clearly, my cataracts are working overtime and I am missing something obvious. Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: What is the generated HTML?  Most browsers compensate for poorly formed HTML by automatically inserting closing tags where it thinks it is appropriate.  Some do a better job than others.

Comment: Cimmanon, I'm on Mac and have no way of seeing how IE is parsing it. I was sent a screenshot that showed all the text stricken out. Not sure why it thinks there's no closing tag when it's visible in the PHP. It looks fine on Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Safari is rendering the HTML with closed tags, as are FF and Chrome:  `<p itemprop="price" class="price"><span class="from">From: </span><del><span class="amount">&#36;79</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">&#36;69</span></ins></p>`

Comment: I tried using browser shots.org to double check but their screenshots don't render down far enough onto the page.